# Rails with Stripe Checkout: How can i seed my db with sample charges and use stripe checkout to generate tokens for each charge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, stripe-payments, seeding

So I have a rails app that takes donations for a fund raising project using stripe checkout. I save the stripetokens to my db, and then go back and process them all at once if the project funding goal is met (sorta like kickstarter). I've figured out how to do this and have tested my code on a small number of charges (say like 10) without any problems. Here's my code

```
@project = Project.find(set_project)

# Create new stripe customer
    @customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :card => params[:stripeToken]
        )

# Create new charge
    @charge = Charge.new(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :stripe_token => params[:stripeToken],
        :project_id => @project.id,
        :amount => params[:amount],
        :customer_id => @customer.id
        )
#Save charge to my db
@charge.save
```

Then in my project model

```
# Cycle through all charges for project and process using 
# stripe token and stripe customer id
def charge
    self.charges.each do |x|
        begin
            Stripe::Charge.create(
                :amount => x.amount,
                :currency => 'usd',
                :customer => x.customer_id
            )
        rescue Stripe::CardError => e
            x.error = e
        else
            x.processed = true
            x.save
        end
    end
end
```

Now here's my question. I want to be able to test this code at higher volumes of charges. How can I seed my db with 1,000 or more sample charges and use the stripe checkout script to create a customer and generate tokens for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing all of this in Test mode you would be able to bypass Checkout completely here.

The idea would be to use the Create Card Token [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token) to create the token on your end in Ruby and then create the charge with that token. You could also pass the card details in the `card` hash when creating the customer instead.

Comment: Guess i shoulda spent more time looking at their api docs. thanks